# Certificate signing remotely

Tags: ssl, certificate

From what I know a certificate signing process involves invoking "openssl ca", input CA and a certificate signing request. The process then outputs a certificate signed by CA.

[image: Certificate remote signing?]

How <del>is it possible</del> to setup "openssl ca" and "CA key" in a remote server, then send to them a "signing request" from localhost and get back "signed cert"?

[The following is added after receiving comments that the question was uncleared.]

Are there any open-source certificate signing server/client tools (a google search showed me nothing, maybe I lacked the right keyword?)? I guess the solution involves a server/client wrapper around openssl that additionally do (secure) file transfering and simple handshakes to start/end signing transactions. First I tended to not implement the tool myself as I am not a security expert. Second to my guess such a tool must already exists and I should not reinvent it.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Do you want to know how to create such a system (in which case the question would be too broad) or don't you understand why such a setup would be possible in the first place?

Comment: I want to know how to set it up so that remote signing is possible: which tools for server and client side. Now I've edited the original question.

Comment: openssl does not provide this kind of functionality  by itself. You need to write a server which wraps the signing functionality and a client which accesses it - but again, too broad.

Comment: When openssl does not provide this kind of functionality by itself, I guess a wrapper server/client must only do file transferring (preferably secure) and some simple handshake to start/end the transaction or anything else to concern? Are there available wrappers that do just that?

Comment: And I don't understand why you've said this question is too broad. It isn't broader than calling "openssl ca" with all inputs are available in the same machine. Or such setup leads to something bigger, broader in the certificate world that I am not aware of?

Comment: If you would need help in writing such a wrapper it would be on-topic provided that it already shows enough effort of your own and shows a specific problem you need help with. But in the current form of the question you expect essentially others to solve the problem for you without doing anything yourself. That's why I consider it too broad.

Comment: I actually intended to not writing such a wrapper by myself, considering I am not a certificate expert, but asked for available solutions that I can learn to understand / can verify that it satisfies the security requirements of the system I am working with.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the communication protocol that supports remote certificate signing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Certificate_Management_Environment

a reference implementation: https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

and the backend server behind it: https://github.com/letsencrypt/boulder/

I hope it is the solution I looked for.